# How do I use try() to load an image thumbnail in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Syntax question! How do I use try() with an image thumbnail?

I am using Carrierwave and MiniMagick to manage image uploads in my Rails app. Each uploaded image also gets a :med_thumb thumbnail.

I use this code to display an Avatar image when it is available --

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.try(:image)), user %>
```

How do I try() the :med_thumb of the image instead? I've attempted these lines without success:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.try(:med_thumb)), user %>
<%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.try(:image, :med_thumb)), user %>
<%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.try(image(:med_thumb))), user %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered I can chain the try() function and use that to get to the image thumbnail. This line worked --

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.try(:image).try(:med_thumb)), user %>
```